# SSIS: OutOfMemoryException thrown while loading data from large table

Tags: ssis, out-of-memory, large-data

I have a really large table that I am not able to extract. This table is extracted thanks to the proprietary database ODBC driver that I link into an ADO.NET Source.

The source table has 90,000 rows and 333 columns. I only convert 3 columns between extraction and loading into an Oracle database.

Everytime I run the package, it fails after 66,500 rows loaded with an OutOfMemoryException. I tried to change the batch size to really low value like 10 or 50 but it still fails.

Screenshot of my dataflow:

[image]

NB: For other tables from this database I had to lower batch size under 300 because the amount of column was exceeding the number of available parameters for generated insert queries and was causing the package to fail.

Comment: 90k rows is a small data set to SSIS. Can you post more details?

Are you sure the problem is not on the Oracle side?

Comment: What else is going on in the package? Could you post a screenshot of the data flow? What is the component that is raising the OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: Also, a quick test to see if it's Oracle versus general package wonkiness is to remove your destination and replace it with a Row Count transformation. Does the package complete or does it still throw the exception?

Comment: @Diego: I know the row count is quite small, but the column amount is huge for SSIS inserts as it will generate a parameter for each of them that you multiply by the number of rows. Therefore I do think that such a huge amount of columns can be a problem when processing a package.

Comment: @billinkc: I already used the row count transform on every of my schema tables to evaluate the amount of data without any issue. I updated my question with a screenshot of the data flow.

Comment: Can you check your source data? I think it could very well be a problem of bad data since you are able to load 66,500 rows. I have encountered such issues before and they generally were  related to bad source data.

Comment: @RajivVarma: Thanks, I will check that tomorrow. Of course `COUNT(*)` works without an issue on this table.

Comment: But IMO, COUNT(*) would'nt really care about the data type. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally came up with a solution some times after posting this issue. I simply ended up setting the BatchSize to 1 on the destination for this particular package and it worked. This is the only package where I encountered the issue.